# Android Canvas Printing

Tags: android, canvas

I'm using a canvas for drawing/printing text in my Bluetooth Thermal Printing. I'm using this library (https://github.com/invicnaper/PrintWB/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zj/printdemo/PrintDemo.java) that creates class called PrintPic that functions as a Canvas.

Initializing a PrintPic objects only requires 1 parameter and that's the width. The problem comes with the height. When I send the canvas to be printed out the canvas isn't drawn at the top of the paper; it actually rolls a bit (around 1/3) before starting to print out which means the drawn image it's drawn on the lower 2/3s of the the paper (sidenote, I'm using a label tags paper roll)

Is there a way to make the canvas be drawn at the start instead of rolling over 1/3 before drawing it out? I'd mention that I'm drawing bitmaps images into the printed canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, there wasn't anything wrong with the way I was handling printing. It turns out that the blank space was do to that section of the paper actually been out of the thermal laser reach so there was no way it was going to write in there.